# Bootstrap - Collapse all accordions and show clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a question regarding the accordions used in bootstrap.

On my page there are multiple accordions using different IDs as different content is loaded into each one through Kendo.

What I want to be able to do is collapse all accordions when clicking on a link that opens one accordion...

I guess an example would be

```
#accordion1 //is expanded
#accordion2 //is expanded
#accordion3 //is expanded
#accordion4 //is collapsed

link clicked expands accordion4

\#accordion1 //is expanded
\#accordion2 //is expanded
\#accordion3 //is expanded
\#accordion4 //is expanded
```

but what I want is accordion1, accordion2 and accordion3 to collapse and accordion4 to expand

Is this possible with bootstrap or would I have to create some custom code in Kendo or jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with bootstrap, using data-attribute:

```
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/neeEiio6nDvBHkF9Bl2Q?p=preview) a working example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to use the code you gave me, but I can't get it to work for some reason. I've created an example here http://plnkr.co/edit/zmMy8s1euVlatIb54PXD?p=preview